# Android code - Remember last played song

Tags: android

Is there a way to get the details of last played song in the android music player.

I am developing a music player.

whenever the my music player application is launched I need to start it with the last played song as in the stock android music player.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to get the details of last played song in the android music player.

You are welcome to contact the authors of each "android music player" and ask them if there is an API that you can use for this.

> I need to start it with the last played song as in the stock android music player

There is no single "stock android music player". Device manufacturers can ship whatever music player they want, and many ship their own.

Neither the Music AOSP app nor the Play Music app have a documented and supported API for retrieving last-played song information.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare.
Then do these players use a db to store such information?

Comment: @SamB: Most music players are closed-source, so we do not really have that information, and I have not looked to see what the Music AOSP app does. That being said, unless you are running on a rooted device as root, you cannot get to other apps' files, anyway.

Comment: Thank you CommonsWare for your time and help. I think I will have to read the entire source code of Music AOSP app.

Answer (score 1):

before exiting the application , save the path of music file in the database. load the path when application launch.

the code should be inside try catch

Answer (score 0):

save the track or song id into the XML file when your music player closes and fetch it from that XML resource file when the music player starts.